# nginx proxy_pass not loading images referenced by a relative link

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm running across a strange issue using nginx as a reverse proxy for some apps hosted on github.

The page and referenced JavaScript loads fine, but the images, eg: images/icon.png, are not loading. I'm getting around this for now by using sub_filter to rewrite the relative links to point to the original file address. This is more of a hack than actual fix.

Strangely, the Javascript library is also referenced as a relative link, eg scripts/app.js, and it is loading correctly. I was thinking maybe it's a problem with MIME types, but can't seem to make the images work without the URL rewrite.

Here's the location code snippet:

```
location ~* /app/data {
    rewrite ^/app/data/(.*)$ /app-data/$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host myhost.github.io;
    proxy_pass http://myhost.github.io;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/xml;
    sub_filter_types text/html;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter \"img/ \"http://myhost.github.io/app-data/img/;
}
```